# Javascript asymmetric encryption and authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, encryption-asymmetric, encryption

Some of the guys here are developing an application which incorporates some 'secure areas' accessible by logging in. In the past, the login form and subsequent 'secure' pages were all plain text transmitted over http, as it's an application that goes out for use on shared servers where there is little chance of being able to use SSL (think WordPress and the like). Most people just shrugged their shoulders as that's all they expected - it's hardly a national bank.

We are now thinking of writing the next version using a JavaScript front end, with the advantage of loading all the images & CSS once, then writing HTML into the DOM thereafter with extJS (or maybe jQuery). We'd like to encrypt user input at the client before being sent to the server, then decrypt server output at the browser before being rendered to HTML so as to introduce some sort of security for users. There are also gains to be had with reducing page loading times, as we're only sending gzipped JSON back and forth.

While playing around, we realised that the method we were looking at to encrypt the basic stuff also doubled up as an authentication mechanism for login in the first place.

For simplicity...:

- The user connects to the login page over standard http, where the browser downloads the JavaScript package containing the hashing and encryption algorithms (SHA-256 and AES for example).
- User enters `username`, `password` and `secret` into a login form.
- The browser JavaScript sends a hash of `username` and `password` to the server via AJAX. The `secret` is only stored in JavaScript and is never sent across the internet.
- The server looks up the hash and retrieves `username` and `secret` from the database.
- The server sends a hash (same algorithm as the browser) of `username` and `secret` back to the browser.
- The browser JavaScript creates a hash of `username` and `secret` and compares it to the hash sent back from the server.
- If they are the same, the browser JavaScript encrypts `response` with `secret` and sends the message back to the server.
- The server decrypts the message with `secret` to find the expected `response` and starts a new session.
- Subsequent communications are encrypted and decrypted both ways with `secret`.

There seem to be a few advantages of this type of system, but are we right in thinking:

- The user knows they are talking to their server if the server manages to create a hash of `username` and `secret`, proving the server knows and understands `username` and `secret`.
- The server knows the user is genuine if they manage to encrypt `response` with `secret`, proving the user knows `secret`.
- At no time is `secret` ever transmitted in plain text, or is it possible to determine `secret` from the hash.
- A sniffer will only ever find out the 'secure' URL and detect compressed hashes and encryptions in the query string. If they send a request to to the URL that is malformed, no response is given. If they somehow manage to guess an appropriate request, they still have to be able to decrypt it.

It all seems quick enough as to be imperceptible to the user. Can anyone see through this, as we all just assumed we shouldn't be playing with JavaScript encryption!

Comment: If what you're protecting (that is, the information for which some security is called for) has any value, you should be using a security protocol designed and tested by security experts.  Full stop. Any other course of action is foolhardy.

Comment: Thanks @pointy, although are you suggesting that all WordPress users around the world should switch to SSL?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the information you're protecting. If it's truly valuable (personal info, financial, health-related, whatever), then it should be protected by a real protocol. If for no other reason, think of the potential liabilities ...

Comment: I've seen plenty of 'hacked' WordPress sites, with sad users complaining that they've lost all of their posts. Do you think the developers should stop pushing products like that unless the application code demands a secure transport layer like SSL/TLS?

Comment: Well maybe it's better to think of it this way: would **you** trust some random site that promised some sort of security but which didn't use HTTPS?  I wouldn't, at least not with any information I considered sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your input Pointy. I've started a new question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7434554/184076

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do this. Please use SSL/TLS. See [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/).

Comment: +1 for your link, but could you tell us on which point where you think the method I described above fails?

Comment: I think it fails on step 1. Since you're on an insecure connection, an attacker can inject a `<script>` tag before your crypto code and steal secrets.

Comment: Marked as answered - the consensus around the office is that if we can be bothered enough to write an obscure encryption library to stop people 'sniffing', then some enterprising attacker will definitely be bothered enough to intercept the initial browser-server communication to insert their own script. Passwords wont mean much after that!

Comment: authentication is ok over SSL/TLS. But what if user knows how to use tools like curl, open-ssl, and gets "authenticated ssl session", and then afterwards he does a malicious thing like post wrong JSON data (online retail apps,  banking apps, etc).

So authorization is in question. I do not see any other solutions beside AES of some kind, and the encryption done in browser.

Comment: The only thing that's harmful here is not answering the question, not summarizing links, etc.
In reality JS has a good amount of purposes.

Comment: That article is really difficult to read in 2018 because the world seems so different now. It sounds like SSL was rare and expensive back then.

Answer (score 2):

If you can provide a single SSL site to deliver your JavaScript securely (to avoid the attack mentioned above), then you can use the opensource Forge library to provide cross-domain TLS connections to your other sites after generating self-signed certificates for them. The Forge library also provides other basic crypto stuff if you opt to go in a different direction. Forge has an XMLHttpRequest wrapper that is nearly all JavaScript, with a small piece that leverages Flash's socket API to enable cross-domain communication.

http://digitalbazaar.com/2010/07/20/javascript-tls-1/

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Comment: If only somebody created such a site... Still, if the code isn't properly locked down, it could be tainted via XSS...